# Cakephp $query->isEmpty() not working

Tags: cakephp

the php if statement below does not work. the query (cases) is empty but it wont show the else statement when it is empty.

```
<?php foreach ($cases as $case): ?>
                    <?php if(!$cases->isEmpty()): ?>            
                    <tr>
                        <td><?= h($case->plaintiff) ?> </td>
                        <td><?= h($case->defendant) ?></td> 
                        <td><?= h($case->case_number) ?></td>
                        <td><?= $this->Html->link(_('View'), ['controller' => 'Cases', 'action' => 'view', $case->id], array('class' => 'btn btn-xs btn-success')) ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php else: ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4">No Related Cases</td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: i figured it out. I just put the if statement outside the foreach loop. duh!!! Its working now but if anyone has a better solution please share

Comment: Iterating empty result sets is like iterating empty arrays, ie there is no need to call `isEmpty()` in the first place, unless you need this information for something else.

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version (last line in vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt or lib/Cake/VERSION.txt)

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out. I just put the if statement outside the foreach loop. duh!!! Its working now but if anyone has a better solution please share